# get next image on scroll in android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have an `ImageView` inside a `RelativeLayout`.It gets images from `database`.I want to add scroll-event to it such that when image is scrolled I should get next and previous image based on direction of scroll.

How can I do that in android?

Comment: Have you used any listview for displaying images?

Comment: Agreed with SpK. [Use a `ListView`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview).

Comment: No , i m directly using imageview.So I should use a listview inside the relativelayout?

Comment: Yes. If you use `ListView` it will be more efficient with as per **Eric**'s suggestion or you can use [onScrollListener](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/) for your `ListView` to load more your images from database.

Comment: Can u tell me how to implement using onScrollListener?

Answer (score 0):

### [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html)

- Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the list or grid has been scrolled.

Example for implementing the `onScrollListner` as per below code -

```
//Here is where the magic happens
this.getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){

//useless here, skip!
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

//dumdumdum
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
    {
        //what is the bottom iten that is visible
        int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;             

        //is the bottom item visible & not loading more already ? Load more !
        if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){
            Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
});
```

Have a look at [this example](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-dynamicaly-load-more-items-to-the-listview-never-ending-list/) and you can also use this [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541966/940096) also